# How can I return all records in each group except the last one in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

I know that `limit` clause can limit the number of records to be returned from the beginning of the end of each group. How can I return all records except the last one in each group... Thank you in advance for the insight!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `rowNo()` function in DolphinDB. For example:

```
select * from t context by id having rowNo(id) < size(id) - 1
```